# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateTransactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to integrate spring with hibernate and I have spring-orm .4.3.6 jar file in my project.But still I am getting below error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateTransactionManager
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
```

Tried googling it.But did not find answer.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This class is coming out of the `spring-orm` dependency (notice the `hibernate5` package in there. There is equally `hibernate3` and `hibernate4` packages in the same jar not to break compatibility).

[The Maven Coordinates are](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.3.10.RELEASE):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks...it's working.But what was problem with 4.3.6.RELEASE.Is 4.3.6.RELEASE version not compatible?